# Census dataset alternatives

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I'm looking to replace some of my code samples which use the [Census dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census+Income). Criticism is that there is some bias and ML fairness issues around this popular dataset. What other public datasets for binary classification which include both categorical and numerical features as well as a fair amount of examples can be relevant?

Candidates are:

- [KDD Cup 1999](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/KDD+Cup+1999+Data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicago Taxi dataset is another option with large number of records and multiple feature types: categorical, numerical and buckets